# Make nav bar change color on scroll?

Tags: html, css

It's complicated to put it in words, but here I go.
Alright so at the moment I'm working on a project that requires me too do one thing. That thing being when the nav bar gets too a certain point I want the color to change. So let's say I have a nav bar white, and underneath that it's gray. How do I go about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do it with HTML/CSS but this work

**Javascript/jQuery**

```
$( window ).scroll(function() {
  if ($( window ).scrollTop() > 500) {
    $('.nav').addClass('updated-color')
  } else {
    $('.nav').removeClass('updated-color')
  }
})
```

**CSS**

```
.nav {
  background-color: white;
}
.nav.updated-color {
  background-color: gray;
}
```